# why does while(*s++ == *t++) not work to compare two strings

Tags: c, pointers, string-comparison

I'm implementing `strcmp(char *s, char *t)` which returns <0 if `s<t`, 0 if `s==t`, and >0 if `s>t` by comparing the fist value that is different between the two strings.

implementing by separating the postfix increment and relational equals operators works:

```
for (; *s==*t; s++, t++)
    if (*s=='\0')
        return 0;
return *s - *t;
```

however, grouping the postfix increment and relational equals operators doesn't work (like so):

```
while (*s++ == *t++)
    if (*s=='\0')
        return 0;
return *s - *t;
```

The latter always returns 0. I thought this could be because we're incrementing the pointers too soon, but even with a difference in the two string occurring at index 5 out of 10 still produces the same result.

Example input:
`strcomp("hello world", "hello xorld");`

return value:
`0`

My hunch is this is because of operator precedence but I'm not positive and if so, I cannot exactly pinpoint why.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're breaking the loop on the comparison of two characters `w` and `x` in your example, but then returning the difference between the characters after `w` and `x`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau That looks like it'd make a good answer.

Comment: @Caleb numzero's got my back below for that.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you John!

Comment: @Matthew don't thank me. Thank the knife!

Comment: if `if (*s=='\0')` there is no guarantee `t == 0` so `return 0` may give incorrect results.

Comment: You should consider tests before your loop of `if (!s && !t) return 0; if ( s && !t) return 1;` and `if (!s &&  t) return -1;` to handle the cases where one or both pointers are `NULL`. Returning the results of a dual *ternary* will ensure the return is always `-1`, `0` or `1`, e.g. `return *s - *t ? *s < *t ? -1 : 1 : 0;` (depending on what you want your function to do -- can make processing the result in a `switch()` much easier.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for your comment David, the latter part about the dual ternary would be a great way to optimize, I didn't think of that. This was merely just an exercise to help me learn about pointers (coming from more high-level languages), which is why I didn't include the edge cases before the loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Re: `!s` and `!t` tests --> Maybe.  `NULL` pointers are UB for the STL `strcmp()`.  Testing might be good, but it is hiding an error.  If obligated to test for `NULL`, I''d use `if (s==NULLL || t==NULL)` and handle those pathological cases there. For "happy path" values, I do not want to test them more than once for `NULL`-ness.  Also you might enjoy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297068/2410359).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - good point, I forgot we were wearing 2 hats here. (and yes, that is a very enjoyable link -- the dual-conditionals is an improvement over the dual-ternary) I guess we could add `#ifdef __cplusplus` and check against `nullptr` -- but then `nullptr` isn't required by the standard. Sticky wicket...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  Please only tag a question with C or C++ as the answers usually vary greatly and they should not be mixed anyway. I've thus suggested to remove the C++ tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in the `for` loop, the increment (`s++, t++` in your case) is *not* called if the condition (`*s==*t` in your case) is false. But in your `while` loop, the increment is called in that case too, so for `strcomp("hello world", "hello xorld")`, both pointers end up pointing at `o`s in the strings.

Answer (score 4):

Since you always increment `s` and `t` in the test, you should refer to `s[-1]` for the termination in case of equal strings and `s[-1]` and `t[-1]` in case they differ.

Also note that the order is determined by the comparison as `unsigned char`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int strcmp(const char *s, const char *t) {
    while (*s++ == *t++) {
        if (s[-1] == '\0')
            return 0;
    }
    return (unsigned char)s[-1] - (unsigned char)t[-1];
}
```

Following the comments from LL *chux*, here is a fully conforming implementation for perverse architectures with non two's complement representation and/or `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`:

```c
int strcmp(const char *s0, const char *t0) {
    const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char *)s0;
    const unsigned char *t = (const unsigned char *)t0;

    while (*s++ == *t++) {
        if (s[-1] == '\0')
            return 0;
    }
    return (s[-1] > t[-1]) - (s[-1] < t[-1]);
}
```

Comment: I apologize in advance for acting like a language lawyer, as your solution obviously works. But is technically undefined behavior when you increment `s` or `t` past the null char (assuming that's how long the string was allocated for).

Comment: @selbie: well the language-lawyer in me says it is defined behavior to make a pointer point one past the last element of the array. It is undefined behavior to make it point before the array or after the element one past the last one. You can check **6.5.6 Additive operators** where many such cases are analysed. Dereferencing the `s` pointing just after the `'\0'` would have undefined behavior, but `s[-1]` is fine.

Comment: @selbie If you would like a LL concern there are 2 here, both one the edge of C.:  In a non-two's complement machine (they don't exist anymore AFAIK) the the access to `s,t` should be as `unsigned char *` to distinguish -0 and + 0.   `unsigned char)s[-1]` --> `((unsigned char *)s)[-1]`.  when `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` the subtraction give the wrong answer.  The classic alternative uses the idiom `(a>b) - (a<b)`.  Still a good answer UV.

Comment: I meant when `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` (which happens with an _unsigned_ `char` as wide as `int`).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I wonder if Unisys latest systems still have ones' complement representations (emulated?) https://www.enterpriseai.news/2015/05/20/new-unisys-clearpath-system-outperforms-mainframe-offerings/

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Perhaps so.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes I thought having a pointer to right before an array is valid  as having one behind it's last member. Thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is giving the right advice, but are still hardwired to inlining those increment operators within the comparison expression and doing weird off by 1 stuff.

The following just feels simpler and easier to read. No pointer is ever incremented or decremented to an invalid address.

```
while ((*s == *t) && *s)
{
    s++;
    t++;
}
return *s - *t;
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295514/why-does-whiles-t-not-work-to-compare-two-strings#comment108437974_61295614).

Answer (score 3):

For completeness in addition to what was already well answered about the wrong offset during subtraction:

`*s - *t;` is incorrect when `*s, *t` is negative.

The standard C library specifies that string functions compare *as if* `char` was `unsigned char`.  Thus  code that subtracts  via a `char *` gives the wrong answer when the characters are negative.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).
>   C17dr § 7.24.1 3

```
int strcmp(const char *s, const char *t) {
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;
  const unsigned char *ut = (const unsigned char *) t;
  while (*us == *ut && *us) {
    us++;
    ut++;
  }
  return (*us > *ut) - (*us < *ut);
}
```

This code also addresses [obscure concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295514/why-does-whiles-t-not-work-to-compare-two-strings#comment108437974_61295614) of non-2's complement access of -0 and `char` range exceeding `int`.